# How to manually create data query index in Apache IoTDB to deal with large time span queries?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

In Apache IoTDB, how can I manually create a query index? Now the query process with a relatively large time span, such as situations to query monthly data, will be difficult and slow. Anyone know are there any solution for this? If query index cannot be created, what functions in IoTDB can I use to create index to ease this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of Apache IoTDB is for the model design level, so IoTDB only has indexes for time series and timestamps. If you want to speed up the query for larger timescale, you can put the parameters you frequently want to check to the time series path to avoid them processing value filtering queries. Also, you can use `tag`, which can be used to query the path of time series, and an inverted index will be maintained in Apache IoTDB.